Saving rows in a row/column table/tbody HTML page with javascript functions
I am a back end (python/ETL/Java) programmer that is retired. I am trying now to build a web app. So far I have a row of dropdowns, dates and text boxes. I can duplicate rows through an "Add Row" button. Javascript affects about half of the HTML elements in the row.
Say I load the page to Google and then add 10 rows. They appear on the page. If I refresh the page, the added rows disappear. I have labored long on this and have found no solution. Do I need to start from scratch and just do most of it in repeated HTML or is there a way to add rows programmatically and then have them persist and reload after a page reset.
I realize that this question may be elementary to an experienced front-end developer. I an old back-end programmer that needs a bit of help. Thanks.

The problem is that changes made on the client side using JavaScript are not saved after reloading the page - they are valid only in the current browser session.
I can offer two solutions right off the bat.

You can save the data of these strings using localStoroge / sessionStorage
Either save the data on the server via API, when the page is refreshed, the data will be loaded from it.

If you have any more questions, ask away!
